# Sum of row in sql with average and difference

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Required Output:

```
 PName      Total   Average Difference
 GSU         20       25       5
 MST         30       25      -5
Costruct     25       25       0
```

Table Value

```
  PName      cost
  GSU       10
  MST       15
  GSU       10
  Constuct  25
  MST       15
```

Query

```
 SELECT PName, SUM(cost) AS cost  FROM [Table_name] group by  PName
```

My Query given me first two column  also i need **Average** and **Difference**

how do I get it from Sql Query?

Comment: Why Average column has value 25? What is the calculation for this Average?

Comment: @semicolon sum of Total Column/3  (20+30+25)/3

Comment: @RigertaDemiri I want average of value which I will get in group by query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
WITH Tab AS
(
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
  ('GSU'     , 10),
  ('MST'     , 15),
  ('GSU'     , 10),
  ('Constuct', 25),
  ('MST'     , 15)) T(pname, cost)
)
SELECT
    pname,
    SUM(cost) Total,
    MAX(TotalSum)/COUNT(*) OVER() Average,
    MAX(TotalSum)/COUNT(*) OVER()-SUM(cost) Difference
FROM (
  SELECT cost, pname, SUM(cost) OVER () TotalSum
  FROM Tab
) T GROUP BY pname
```

**Output (not sorted):**

```
pname    Total       Average     Difference
-------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Constuct 25          25          0
GSU      20          25          5
MST      30          25          -5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.PName, SUM(t1.Cost) AS Total, t2.AvgCost, t2.AvgCost-SUM(t1.Cost) AS Diff
FROM Table t1,
(SELECT avg(cost) AS AvgCost FROM Table) t2
GROUP BY t1.PName
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hi Pravin, this is the query that you want :**

```
select 
Pname, 
sum(cost) as Total, 
sum(cost)/count(cost) as Average, 
sum(cost) - sum(cost)/count(cost) as Difference 
from [Table_name]  
group by Pname
```

Comment: Output do not match: for MST it yields *MST, 30, 15, 15*